# Function does not seem to get called when using a foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, wordpress-rest-api

I don't know much about PHP, but I needed to write a few lines to add custom keys to the response of my API in WordPress:

```
<?php
$customFields = array("maker", "model", "ou", "prod_year", "barrel_length", "stock", "stock_length", "ejector", "links",
    "chokes", "condition", "original_case", "price");

function rest_get_post_field( $post, $field_name, $request ) {
    return get_post_meta( $post[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_fields' );
function add_custom_fields(){
    foreach($customFields as $field) {
        register_rest_field( 'post',$field,
        array(
            'get_callback'  => 'rest_get_post_field',
            'update_callback'   => null,
            'schema'            => null,)
        );
    }
}

?>
```

The code above does not work. At first I was going to call the `register_rest_field` method for each of the custom fields, like this for example:

```
function add_custom_fields(){
        register_rest_field( 'post','maker',
        array(
            'get_callback'  => 'rest_get_post_field',
            'update_callback'   => null,
            'schema'            => null,)
);
```

I have tested this and it works. However, creating a string array of the custom field names and then looping over them seems like a much better solution with much fewer lines of code. Is there a way to make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `customFields` variable is not a global variable, the function will interpret it as null. You need to pass your custom keys array as argument of your function.

```
function add_custom_fields($fields)
{
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        register_rest_field( 'post',$field,
        array(
            'get_callback'  => 'rest_get_post_field',
            'update_callback'   => null,
            'schema'            => null,)
        );
    }
}
```

Then, specific in your [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) function that you need to pass one argument.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'add_custom_fields', 10, 1);
```

And lastly, call your [do_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/) function specifying `customFields` variable as parameter of your function.

```
do_action('rest_api_init', $customFields)
```

Check for more informations: [Function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

---

Alternatively (if what you have to do allows it), just define your custom keys array inside your function.

```
function add_custom_fields()
{
    $customFields = array("maker", "model", "ou", "prod_year", "barrel_length", "stock", "stock_length", "ejector", "links", "chokes", "condition", "original_case", "price");
    foreach($customFields as $field) {
        register_rest_field( 'post',$field,
        array(
            'get_callback'  => 'rest_get_post_field',
            'update_callback'   => null,
            'schema'            => null,)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. My code would have been fine in JavaScript, since the variable would automatically have been global. I assumed it was the same for PHP.